# Crear salto de linea automático en div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear saltos de línea al menú de mi plantilla, inserté  `word-wrap:break-word;` a mi elemento `<ul>`, pero no funcionó.

Link de la plantilla: https://themesbrand.com/veltrix/layouts/vertical/index.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor dale mas pixeles al ancho de cada item para que quepa correctamente. Width:160px quizás.

Comment: en la consola hacele botón derecho al `ul` y dale a copy outer html así lo vemos en texto ( copiate también los css ) lo mas seguro es que haya un `inline-block` sin ancho máximo

Comment: Estimados, dejé el enlace... La verdad no soy pro en css... Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Lo siento Jhon, pero por más que fuerce a la plantilla a crear lo que muestras en tu imagen, no logro reproducirlo, pues el salto de línea se hace de forma automática. ¿No estás tocando nada más del CSS? Por favor revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JheymanMejia teniendo la versión reducida del menú dentro de la plantilla si que se puede reproducir

Comment: @matahombres vale, ya te entiendo. En dicho caso tu respuesta es correcta, se debe aplicar dentro de las clases `.enlarged #wrapper .left.side-menu #sidebar-menu ul > li`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La propiedad que controla los saltos de linea es el `white-space`

`word-break` se utiliza más cuando tienes una palabra demasiado grande y se sale del container principal (un ejemplo de eso sería un link muy largo que es todo texto seguido)

Añadiendo al `li` la propiedad `white-space:initial`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente es lo que estaba tratando de conseguir.